# How to fix blank white screen when debugging on Flutter?

Tags: debugging, flutter

When I try to debug my Flutter project the app launch but gets stuck on a blank screen.

I use proxy configuration because of corporate environment.

I've tried to reinstall all the components and SDKs, different IDEs, different emulators or AVDs configurations, even on a physical device. I can run the app without problems and debugger works on Android Java projects.

Thats the only error shown : Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error